# Why is bipolar capacitor labelled with plus and minus?

Tags: capacitor, bipolar

I need an unpolarised 3300 uF capacitor for an audio amplifier. After googling on the internet, I came to the conclusion that the only way to get such a high value is to use a so-called bi-polar capacitor. However, what bothers me is that these bipolar capacitors are also labelled with plus and minus. Why this labelling when a bipolar capacitor can replace a non-polar capacitor?

Comment: Can you show a photo what you have? A 3300uF cap sounds like polarized electrolytic, not non-polar/bipolar.

Comment: @Justme I don't have it in physical form, I am just reading datasheets like this one https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/ABA0000C1053-947519.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked datasheet looks like they used the same lead finishing equipment as for polarized capacitors - with one long and one short lead, copied the drawing over, and forgot to erase the polarization legend. Same thing with verifying the correct polarity in section 2.2(2), they just pasted in boilerplate text which is N/A for bipolar caps.